# is there any way to change datatype of index field once data has been pushed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

i want to change the datatype of one field in my opensearch index from long to string. Is there any way to do so. I have already pushed data in that index so it is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll need to reindex. The good news is that it can be done with the relatively fast [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) without running your whole ETL pipeline.